# Why my aggregation filter does not find string values (BIRT)

Tags: java, string, filter, birt, aggregation

I do not know why but my aggregation filter does not find some string values. MY data table:

```
valandos    indikacija  craft
4   A   NULL
31  A   EL
70  A   ELI
208,5   A   ME
10  A   MEI
4   A   RAN
47,5    A   SUV
10  B   EL
81  B   ELI
77,5    B   ME
31,5    B   SUV
61,5    C   EL
212,5   C   ELI
153 C   ME
15,5    C   SUV
```

I try to SUM hours which have same craft for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/146OC.png)
But I do not any data from this aggregation. But if I try something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPnHv.png)

IT WORKS FINE.
SO my question is why my filter on "cratf" column does not work. I tried look for different values but it still does not return results. 
"craft" and "indikacija" are both string values.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on "craft" column:
dataSetRow["craft"]=="ME"

Can somebody explain why dataSetRow["craft"]=="ME" works but dataSetRow["craft"].equals("ME") does not?